# Simplify 3rd party component prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I'm using a React component, `markdown-to-jsx`, to turn markdown strings into HTML. It has the ability to take custom components I've created and use them to render Custom tags. However, the prop for doing so is so verbose that it's a bit annoying and I was hope to simplify it, but am having trouble achieving that.

example: I want to add a component, Dice, to my markdown render. This works perfectly, but wow, it's a lot of typing:

```js
import Markdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';
import Dice from './Dice';
...
<Markdown options={{ overrides: { Dice: { component: Dice } } }}>
  {markdownContent}
</Markdown>
```

Wow, what if I had several components I wanted to add? Ugly. So, I had an idea: write a component that uses `markdown-to-jsx` and simplify the props:

```js
import Markdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';
(other imports)
...

// Take the original component and run a map to create that ugly verbose code.
function Md({ components, children }) {
  const comps = components.map((c) => ({ [c.name]: { component: c } }));
  return <Markdown options={{ overrides: { comps } }}>{children}</Markdown>;
}

...
<Md components={[Dice, Attack, Foo]}>
  {markdownContent}
</Md>
```

Pretty cool, right? No. It doesn't work. I keep getting these errors:

- `<Dice /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.`
- `Warning: The tag <Dice> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter`

Why does the ugly version work but mine does not???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, `components.map` returns an array but `overrides` needs an object, in your case you could use `component.reduce` to aggregate the values into an object instead.

```
const comps = components.reduce((accumulator, c) => { 
    accumulator[c.name] = {component: c};
    
    return accumulator;
}, {});
```

It also slightly affects the return statement:

```
return <Markdown options={{ overrides: comps }}>{children}</Markdown>;
```

Comment: I have been trying forever to get this to work but the code won't even build to the point of me getting where my previous errors would pop up in console. There seem to be a number of syntax errors here. It doesn't understand the spread syntax (unexpected token) + (declaration or statement expected), where the colon is after `[c.name]` it expects a comma, and there's a bunch more errors.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll update my code so that it's more compatible, and I'll check for syntax errors

Comment: It should be okay now

Comment: Love it. Thank you very much for your help. Now I don't have to type a novel just to send a list of components. A novel that has so many opportunities for me to forget a bracket or a comma. Wow!

Comment: Although, I noticed I missed the `component` key in the object for a component, I updated the code accordingly, my bad.